# Strange <img> placement behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image within HTML page which behaves strangely.

I seems to be placed on the opposite side of the div (i.e - left to right), but any small refresh cause it to go back to its place (right to left where it should be)

With "small refresh" I mean one of the following:

1. Open **Inspect Element** and uncheck any css attribute the recheck it again.
2. Any js adding a field to the form or updates its value.
3. Sometimes even clicking the div cause it to go back.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

**EDIT:**

Got it solved finally. The problem was an extra "ltr" somewhere...
It still strange that it acts this way but now I don't care :-)

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you show some code to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Can you simulate the same on jsfiddle ?

Comment: I had similar problem using Chrome. IMO it has highly 'intelligent' cache management. After clear all local data it gets back to predicable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you using ? I have seen this before. Your div may need 1 pixel more to be placed correctly. If you inspect it, it is possible that a css will be apply on the div that make him slide to his correct position. Try to play with css to find a configuration where he dont move (adding a margin top, for example, or adding  clear:both elements somewhere.)